# Header Information does not match array. deletechars argument

Tags: python, genfromtxt

I am trying to create a numpy array from a geosoft formatted xyz text file. The format uses a '/' to start the header file, then space delimited after. I believe numpy sees the '/' and assigns as column zero.

Header info looks like this

> /  Line Aircraft Flight   Date JulL      Time DateU     TimeU Zn     Easting     Northing        Lat        Long    xTrack   ZFid_ms      KFid      AFid       TFRAWT       TFUNCT     Mag4D      VecX      VecY      VecZ     VecTF MagRatio   GPSHt   Undul Sats HDop DGPS   RadAlt  BaroHPa     Temp    Humid CurrAmps Dn Up Samp Live   RawTC    RawK    RawU   RawTh  Cosm  LRange LStr LErr

```
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, deletechars="/", usecols=(0,18,20,21,22,23),invalid_raise=False, names=True,dtype=None)
```

data.dtype.names results in below, first column did not create a valid column name

> ('f0', 'TFRAWT', 'Mag4D', 'VecX', 'VecY', 'VecZ')

I thought deletechars was built for this purpose? Am I not using it correctly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The header contains a '/' at the start which is causing problems. I would prefer not to read write an entire file to remove the very first character of the file to remedy the issue. Is there another way I can resolve this issue? Is there a function I am missing in genfromtxt? Can I edit an existing data.dtype.names before/during/after import? Can I create a list and assign as data.dtype.names?